# How to mock an external domain/resource using mswjs?

Tags: msw

I'd like to use mswjs to mock some external APIs (not on localhost), I can't find any information online on wether this is possible or not.

I need to mock both localhost resources and external resources at the same time.

May someone provide an example configuration of how to do it?

I'm using the Storybook addon if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mock any resource with MSW, regardless of whether it's external or local.

Provide the path to the resource you wish to intercept, and describe the mock logic in your response resolver function:

```js
import { rest } from 'msw'

export const handlers = [
  rest.get('https://api.github.com', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json({ mocked: true }))
  })
]
```

Take a look at the [project's README](https://github.com/mswjs/msw#usage-example) that features the example of mocking an external resource.